# Argument problem

Tags: complex-numbers

What would be the argument of 
$i^i$? What are the possible ways to find it out?

Comment: Its real !. No argument !

Comment: No it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

$i^i = e^{i\ln i} = e^{i\cdot i\pi/2} = e^{-\pi/2}$, so the argument is $0$.

Comment: Great!! I really liked your answer.

Comment: Isn't it shorter to start from $i=\mathrm e^{i\tfrac\pi2}$?